# Facebook Like Button for multiple posts on one page: is it possible?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I've been able to properly implement the Facebook Like Button for my WordPress single.php pages, where the link and a thumbnail from the post is correctly referred.

I've also been able to get the FB Like button to reference the correct link on a list of posts on the index.php. However, the thumbnails are being pulled randomly on the index.php.

Do I understand this correctly: that Facebook only allows you to specify one thumbnail per page with its Open Graph method in the  space?

Just want a confirmation, because I can't find anything the definitively says this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can specify multiple thumbnails on a page and then the user can pick from that selection of images. From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/):

> You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images
>   with your page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get like the like button after each post, either you have to add this script underneath the POST QUERY

```
<span class='st_fblike_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_email_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_sharethis_vcount'></span>
```

stLight.options({publisher: "782110c4-838d-408f-8393-98897995ced4"});

Or install SHARETHIS plugin and configure it, choose AFTER EVERY POST...